# How to split a name in two parts after 2 white space?

Tags: javascript

Looking for one solution like. I had a word with three white space.so I want to split it into two line after 2nd white space.

Example : -

**Coding and Unit Testing**

I want that in two line after and like this

1st Line

```
  Coding and
```

2nd Line

```
  Unit Testing
```

How can I do it in javascript?

Thanks inadvance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to say where the white spaces are, then you can solve it.

Comment: make the question clear

Comment: You could do this with a regular expression.  (... and I agree with @ManuVarghese - your question could be more clear)

Comment: what will the output for this string ? **self try coding and unit testing , If get stuck then ask help on stackoverflow with more clear question**

Comment: Hi All , I guess my question is not clear. Ok here in details . I am having a list of array of names like TEST BOX, TEST BOX TWO, TESTING TOOLS , ENGINEERING AND TESTING, SOFTWARE AND HARDWARE etc. So I want to separate them. For example suppose I get TEST BOX, TEST BOX TWO. So for TEST BOX I don't want to change any thing but when I get TEST BOX TWO. It should separate TEST BOX as one string and another string as TWO. So by two white space I mean that in any name the 2 space should break as separate string.

Comment: So I want to divide all the names into two string if it has space more then one in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my answer i will assume some things:

- The test cases can be an random string with random white spaces (evens or odds).
- You will always want to split in 2 equal parts if possible, if not it will give priority to the first group.

Said that i will try with 4 test cases with different lengths. The idea here is to tokenize the string splitting by the white spaces. Then we cut the array in 2 and return as an array.

```js
const test1 = "Coding and Unit Testing";
const test2 = "Coding and Unit Testing is fun";
const test3 = "Coding and Unit Testing is fun :D";
const test4 = "Coding and Unit Testing is fun isn't it";

function customSplit(str) {
  const s = str.split(" ");
  const limit = Math.ceil(s.length / 2);
  const first = s.slice(0, limit).join(" ");
  const second = s.slice(limit).join(" ");
  console.log(`${first}\n${second}\n`);
  return [first, second];
}

customSplit(test1);
customSplit(test2);
customSplit(test3);
customSplit(test4);
```

Comment: Thanks Giwiro you got the correct understanding of what I was expecting.